# Is there a map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ which is $\Bbb R$-linear but not $\Bbb C$-linear?

Tags: linear-transformations

Can there be a map which is linear transformation in $\mathbb{C(R)}$ (vector space of complex nos over reals) and not in $\mathbb{C(C)}$ (vector space of complex nos over complex nos)?
I want an example or a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean by $\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{R})$ as the set of continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to itself?  What about $\Bbb{C}(\Bbb C)$?  How about $f(z) = \text{Re}(z)+(\text{Im}(z))^2$?  Restricted to the real numbers as input, it is simply the identity function and is clearly linear, but is clearly not linear for non-real inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex conjugate map $$\Bbb C\to\Bbb C\\z\mapsto \overline z$$ is $\Bbb R$-linear but not $\Bbb C$-linear.

Comment: thanks a lot. Brilliant example.